# Is it possible to build google play service lib only for GCM in eclipse?

Tags: android, google-play, google-cloud-messaging, admob, google-play-services

I have created an android app in eclipse. When upload app in google play store,
Google has put a new option on their Pricing and Distribution page of their Google Play Developer Console that requires publishers to declare if they have ads or not. I got following warning message.

> We detected Ad SDKs in one or more of your active APKs:
>
> version: XXXXX, sdk: AdMob
>
> If your app is serving ads, please change your ads declaration to
>   'Yes'. Failure to accurately declare the presence of ads is a policy
>   violation and may result in your app's removal from Google Play. You
>   can visit our Help Center to learn more.

Our app does not have ads, yet we are being flagged as having the AdMob SDK. I think it's because we are using google play service library which  includes a transitive dependency on AdMob.

Is it possible to build google play service lib only for GCM in eclipse ?

If yes, then how ?

Comment: I guess not sure, no separate instance is there for eclipse.

Comment: You may be able to use proguard to exclude the libs in Play Services that you do not need. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for android studio dude, Google play services has a separate instance for Google Could messaging and you can add it into gradle like this.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:x.x.x'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about eclipse. But in android studio we can do that.

Google Cloud Messaging

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0
```

you can check more on [Google developer Link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)